# Uploading file on sharepoint with python causes uploaded file to retain headers in the content

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When I submit the post request using my script, I do not encode the data and prepare the post request as such:

```
postheader.update({'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose','Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest':formdigestvalue, 'binaryStringRequestBody':'true'})

filetoupload = {'file':(filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')}
posturl = projectConfig.sharepointurl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Shared Documents/release_doc/"+project+"')/files/add(url='"+filename+"', overwrite='true')"
response = requests.post(posturl, headers=postheader, files=filetoupload, cookies=postcookies)
```

I took a look at the file that I uploaded using my script and it has the following headers still attached in the content:

```
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"; filename="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

<file content>
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1--
```

However the file that was uploaded through firefox did not have these headers. I'm thinking I need to call a sharepoint function (if there is a REST API that does that) to process the file after it is uploaded or if there's a method in the python requests that can dispose off these headers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with python, but I can provide you with Fiddler data, when performing exactly the same request as you are trying to do.

This is a screen with headers:

[image]

Text presentation:

```
POST https://s.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@FolderName)/Files/add(url=@FileName,overwrite=true)?@FolderName=%27documentprojet%27&@FileName=%27myfile.zip%27 HTTP/1.1
X-RequestDigest: 0x051ED75F5F96EE3985275F...6,22 Nov 2016 19:57:47 -0000
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...iOiJSUOvsukS16Q
host: s.sharepoint.com
content-length: 6061
Connection: close
```

Take a note on `content-length` header. The body is simply file binary presentation.

Comment: I'm not sure why your request doesn't have the content-disposition header in the payload. I see this being part of the request body when I upload even from firefox.

Comment: Hmmm.. don't know. May be that's not required, since that's work fine for me. Try to experiment with different headers.

Comment: Actually even if the content-disposition is not there, the content boundary is always defined and in your case it isn't. Firefox does this too and in the content-type header identifies the boundary. The payload is then encased within this boundary. Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------6995377611008

Comment: Actually, talking through this helped. I came upon a post which talks about the requirement for the boundary to be specified in the content-type header. 


"If you are using one of multipart/* content types, you are actually required to specify the boundary parameter in the Content-Type header, otherwise the server (in the case of an HTTP request) will not be able to parse the payload."
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

I'm going to give this a try. Append the Content-Type header with the boundary if I can figure out how to get that.

Comment: So back to square one...I can set the content-type boundary correctly and still the uploaded file includes the headers as shown in OP

Comment: Did you set `content-length`?

Comment: Yes it gets set automatically. I did verify that it was getting set appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using

```
request.post(data=open(filename, 'rb'))
```

instead of

```
request.post(files={'files':open(filename, 'rb')})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Java.
Fixed it by NOT using multipart-form

```
public void uploadWithREST(File file, String __REQUESTDIGIST) throws Exception {
    String uploadURL = String.format(uploadURLFormat, excelUploadRelativePath + "/" + file.getName());
    HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
    uploadURL = hostURL + URLEncoder.encode(uploadURL, "utf8");
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadURL);
    setBasicAuthorization(httpPost);
    setRequestDigest(httpPost, __REQUESTDIGIST);
    httpPost.setHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    //MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();  -- do not use
    //builder.addBinaryBody(file.getName(), file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, file.getName());  -- do not use
    EntityBuilder builder = EntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setFile(file);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

    System.out.println(response);
}
```